# ajaxError get error text on bind

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I've looked into other related questions on stackoverflow, and none do what I am searching for.

In my `global.js` I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).ajaxSend(function () { ShowLoading(); });
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function () { HideLoading(); });
    $(document).ajaxError(function (xhr) { ShowPopup(xhr.responseText, 'error', true); });
});
```

Now, instead of `xhr`, I tried with just `responseText` whitouth success. When I throw a new error like this `throw new Exception("My error");` in my C# MVC project, instead of the simple popup I programmed that should pop up from bottom that worked before when I wasn't using `$.ajax({...})` for calling, I just get an error in Chrome's console. How do I skip that error in console and get the actual error text in my script and use it however I want? Can that be done with `document.ajaxError` global function, or do I have to program it on every ajax call? If so, how do I get that message there and then?

Comment: People who woted down this question, explain your selfs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values passed to the `ajaxError` event call back are in the following order

1. event
2. [jqXHR object](http://errorText)
3. settings
4. errorText.

In your code you are accessing only the `event` parameter, which clearly does not have a `responseText` proeprty and you will get `undefined` when you try to access that.

The solution is to use the xhr parameter and then it's `responseText`(if that is what you need to pass to the other method).

```
$(document).ajaxError(function (event,xhr,settings,errorText){ 
     console.log(errorText);
     alert('errorText',errorText);
     alert(xhr.responseText);
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm! I didn't know that in javascript, parameter order is inportant, not the param name. I can call the first parameter whatever I want, but it will always be `event`. One more thing: if I ever wanted to skip this globally used error handler, I need to put `global: false` in my local ajax call. Is that correct?